# Binding 3 things in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have problem with binding 3 things i xaml.

I want to made something like this:

1. I choose product from combobox.
2. Default price from this products is setting in textbox.
3. Now I want for example change this price and bind it to my object 'newSale'

```xaml
<TextBox Name="txtSalePrice" InputScope="Digits" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbProducts, Path=SelectedItem.Price}" \>      
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding ListProducts}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" \>
```

I want to bind value of textbox to property of object 'NewSale' with property 'price', but without change price in selectedProduct.

I have problem with achieve this.

Comment: *"I want to bind value of textbox to property of object 'NewSale' with property 'price', but without change price in selectedProduct."* That's not much of a binding then, is it? Don't try to force unrelated things together, simply use the price from the product as the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I see is to use another property (`Price` for example) bound to your **TextBox**. In you viewmodel, whenever the `SelectedItem` of your **ComboBox** changes, set it into `Price`. And whenever you want to display something else, set manually the value into `Price`.